# Востановление забытого пароля

Tags: сессия, пароль, php

Мне выдает ошибку в 48 строке. У меня вот такой код:

```
<?php
include("connectbd.php");
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $email = trim($email);

    // проверяем, если юзер в таблице с таким же мылом
    $query = "SELECT name, email, password FROM `users` WHERE email ='{$email}' 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT name, email, password FROM `sense` WHERE email ='{$email}'";

    $sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
        //если есть
        $name     = $row[name];
        $email    = $row[email];
        $password = $row[password];

        $message = 'У вас новое сообщение, напоминаем ваш пароль: ' . $password . '';

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";

        # /* дополнительные шапки */

        $headers .= "To: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:iExtrasense.com <ie***nse@gmail.com>\r\n";
        $subject = "Здравствуйте, $name! Напоминание пароля.";

        #
        # /* и теперь отправим из */ 
        mail($email, "=?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $message, $headers);

        echo '<center><h2>Пароль отправлен на Ваш Email!</h2></center> ';

    } else {
        echo '<center><h2>Не зарегистрированный или не правильный Email!</h2></center>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: тут вообще-то строк по меньше чем 48... Вы бы лучше содержание самой ошибки вывели.

Comment: @Maris, даже для интереса сам посчитал =))). Я так и не понял, где на скрине ошибка на линии 48.

Answer (score 1):

В самый низ перед ?> поставьте }, сейчас условие if (!empty($_POST)) открывающую скобку имеет, а закрывающую нет, отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: из-за этого он мне ещё больше ошибок выдает!
http://s019.radikal.ru/i627/1209/b7/8745507bd62d.png

Comment: Покажите что пишется в логе на счет ваших ошибок

Comment: http://s019.radikal.ru/i627/1209/b7/8745507bd62d.png

Comment: Проверяйте настройки соединения с БД, сервер, база данных, логин, пароль.

Answer (score 1):

Судя, по скриншотам,у Вас введен неправильный пароль при подключение к БД. Проверьте его! Кстати Зоркий правильно заметил, у Вас не закрытая }. 
**P.S.** функция, которая отвечает за подключение к БД называется mysql_connect().

Comment: вот и я о том же.

Comment: правильно я ввел пароль!

Comment: значит имя пользователя неправильное =)

Comment: Логично. : )

Comment: А если из консоли MySQL зайти под вашими данными, зайдет?

Comment: Вы в начале фрагмента, тот что тут в вопросе висит сделайте подключение к Бд, у меня есть сомнения, что вы вообще не подключаетесь к БД, а сервер дает стандартные настройки =))

Comment: хех, извините пожалуйста!  это всё моя не внимательность, я забыл к базе подключится!

Comment: Все нормально =), обращайтесь. Вопрос можно закрыть.